# How to see how far a text widget is currently scrolled in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

text_widget.index(tk.CURRENT) gives me the current position in "lineNumber.charOffset" format, which is useful, but I want to know by how much the text widget is currently scrolled by. Essentially, I'm deleting the text upon a click, altering it and doing some behind the scenes work, and then re-displaying it. Naturally, the scroll position gets lost, so I'm trying to use text_widget.yview_scroll(number, "units") to put it back exactly in place, but I don't know how to get the appropriate number. Any thoughts?

Comment: `text_widget.yview()` will give you a list of two numbers, which are the fractions (range 0...1) of the total content that are located at the top and bottom of the widget.  The first one can later be passed to `.yview_moveto()` to return to that scroll position.

Comment: Thank you!! Is there some kind of documentation for this so I don't have to keep asking on stack overflow? Somehow I've been unable to find the tkinter docs. Thanks again!

Comment: @TheMathBoi: from an interactive prompt you can do `print(help(tk.Text))` to get the documentation for the text widget. Also, the [official python documentation on tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html) can show you how to find more help.

Comment: @BryanOakley Actually you only need `help(...)`. The `help` function prints out the doc strings automatically. "*Calling help(thing) prints help for the python object 'thing'*" - from `help(help)`. Basically `help(...)` returns `None`